# How to make keypress oemMinus and oemComma ( + digits) acceptable

Tags: c#

I have a textbox in my application which I only want the user to be able to choose the "minus", "comma", "digits" and "back" from the keyboard. Can only make the user use digits and the back key, the rest doesn't work.

```
private void BoxMaxY_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || 
         !(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.OemMinus || !(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Oemcomma))))
     { 
         e.Handled = true; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your code says: handle if it's not minus or not comma, remove the "!" from those checks.

Comment: Still doenst let me enter the minus and the comma.